# MDI child go behind the first child in c#

Tags: c#, mdichild, mdiparent

i have one MDI called MDIMain and 2 form the first one is MAINMENU and the second one is profile, in my mainmenu form i have a button and if i click the button it shows the profile form but the problem is that when i click the mainmenu form anywhere the profile form go behind the mainmenu.

here is my code: this button is from Mainmenu form

```
private void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    profile frm = new profile();
    frm .MdiParent = this.ParentForm;
    frm .Show();
}
```

edited: this is the code form my mdi

```
private void MDIMAIN_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MAINMENU mn = new MAINMENU();
        mn.MdiParent = this;
        mn.Show();
    }
```

Comment: You aren't showing enough code, but I'm guessing you need this: `frm.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;`

Comment: @LarsTech it's the same it goes behind the first child.

Comment: Post the code that duplicates that for us.  What you have posted so far doesn't do that.

Comment: what do you mean by duplicate? thats the only code i have so far in my first child.

Comment: on the mainmenu, a button click event, i have updated my question.

Comment: @LarsTech see the update of my question.

Comment: `the problem is that when i click the mainmenu form anywhere the profile form go behind the mainmenu.`  This is actually how it's supposed to work.

Comment: how am i going to prevent it? i dont want to use a showdialog if possible. i want the profile form stays on top even if i click the mainmenu form

Comment: It's not clear what you want to have.  Is the MainMenu supposed to be permanently docked?  If so, don't set the MDI Parent.  Make it TopLevel = false, Dock = Top, Border = None and add it as a control: `this.Controls.Add(mn);`

Comment: i will try the other way you show me thank you.